# OpenCv 3.1.0 undefined reference to imread

Tags: opencv, undefined-reference

This is what my code looks like, I got the undefined reference to `imread` and so on:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace std;

using namespace cv;

int main( int argc, const char** argv )
{
    Mat img = imread("MyPicture.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED); //read the image  data in the file "MyPic.JPG" and store it in 'img'

    if (img.empty()) //check whether the image is loaded or not
    {
        cout << "Error : Image cannot be loaded..!!" << endl;
        //system("pause"); //wait for a key press
        return -1;
    }

    namedWindow("MyWindow", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); //create a window with the name "MyWindow"
    imshow("MyWindow", img); //display the image which is stored in the 'img' in the "MyWindow" window

    waitKey(0); //wait infinite time for a keypress

    destroyWindow("MyWindow"); //destroy the window with the name, "MyWindow"

    return 0;
}
```

I am using Codeblocks and the g++ compiler. Also I have linked the `opencv_world310d.lib` to `debug` and `opencv_world310.lib` to `release`.
Plus I have given the path in searchdirectory compiler and linker.
Any hints?

Comment: Where did `opencv_world310d.lib` and `opencv_world310.lib` come from? Are those binaries you built yourself using g++? Or are those some pre-built Visual C++ binaries, perhaps one of the 64bit sets that come in the official distribution package of openCV?

Comment: these are pre-built libraries

Comment: Which specific ones? In the package I'm aware of, there are several different sets (albeit all 64bit and all for MSVC++). Also, are you building a 64bit or 32bit application? Either way, I believe you're using incompatible libraries, and as I haven't seen any prebuilt binaries for g++ on windows, I'd say you have to build your own.

Comment: they are from the x86 directory so  they must be 32 bit version. My windows is 64 bit.The libraries are created when you download and execute the OpenCv 3.1.0 version

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OpenCv undefined reference to \`cv::](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26237482/opencv-undefined-reference-to-cv)